# Skips a line when i run the program again

Tags: java

I have a program that will take in the user input of a make, model, license plate and year of a car and return a key code like a car rental shop. When i ask the user if he wants to rent another car, and he says yes, the program will run again. However, when it runs again, it completely doesnt allow the user to input a make. This is weird because everything else in the program works. The following is a main chunk of my code.

```
 public void run()

{

 input();    

addStuff();

printCode();

  String answer;
  System.out.print("Would you like to rent another car?(Yes or no) ==> ");
  answer =keyboard.next();
  switch(answer)
  {
      case "Yes": case "y": case "YES": case "yes": run();
      break;
      case "No": case "n": case "NO": case "no": System.out.println("Thanks for using Jake's Car Rental Services!");
      break;
      default: System.out.println("Are you sure you can drive? You cant even say yes or no!");
      break;
  }


 }//end run


 public void input()

{

System.out.println("Welcome to Jake's Car Rental Dealership!");

System.out.prinln();

   System.out.print("What is the make of your car? ==> ");
   myMake = keyboard.nextLine();
   System.out.println();
   System.out.print("What is the model and year of your car?(Space between model and year) ==> ");
   myModel = keyboard.next();

   System.out.println();
   System.out.print("What is your liscense plate ID?(Space between each number and letter) ==> ");
   myPlate = keyboard.next();
   myLetter1 = myPlate.charAt(0);
   myLetter2 = myPlate.charAt(1);
   myLetter3 = myPlate.charAt(2);
   myNum = keyboard.nextInt();
   System.out.println();
   print();
   getPlate();


 }//end input
```

Comment: Do you have `keyboard.close()` anywhere in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You might try using nextLine instead of just next()

```
answer = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Are you using java 7?

Answer (score 0):

A problem could be that nextInt() does not take in a new line. So the resulting enter is then picked up later or on the second run of the program